# Renovate: package.json and package-lock.json not in sync

Tags: javascript, renovate

I just configured renovate and it seems to work. Except I get the below message all the time. Is there a way I can manage renovate to run npm install by it's own? So which command should i add to my `renovate.json` file?

I tried `"postUpdateOptions": ["npmDedupe"]` or `postUpgradeTasks` but neither didn't work.

> npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.

Right now to solve this error, I must checkout my renovate branch and run manually npm install.

Comment: I want to add that the renovate bot runs on a mono-repo

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue at my repo.
You can try RENOVATE_UPDATE_LOCK_FILES: "true"

In our case we had some 404 and 403 in the logfile for some private packages.
After solving this by injecting a npmrc string with a token our problem was solved.

Let me know if it helps or if you already got a solution!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).